# Standard deviation of sample proportions (standard error) in R

Tags: r, sampling, standard-error

[This resource](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/wmopen-concepts-statistics/chapter/distribution-of-sample-proportions-4-of-6/) states that the standard deviation of the sampling distribution (the standard error) is equal to:

[image: \sqrt\frac{p(1-p)}{n}]

They provide an example where a population has p=0.6 and samples of n=25 are drawn from this population. Hence the standard error equals:

[image: \sqrt\frac{0.6(1-0.6)}{25}\approx 0.098]

Using R, I'm now trying to validate this calculation of the standard error.

```
set.seed(123)
pop <- c(rep(x = 1, times = 60), rep(x = 0, times = 40))
df <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:1000){

    sample <- sample(x = pop, size = 25)
    df <- rbind(
        df,
        data.frame(mean.prop=mean(sample)))
}

df %>% summarise(se=sd(mean.prop), mean=mean(mean.prop))

se          mean
0.08612411  0.59888
```

Why does my standard error of 0.086 differ so much from the theoretical standard error of 0.098?

Comment: I believe you want to use: `sample(x = pop, size = 25, replace=TRUE)` if not due to the sampling the small population size skews the results.

Comment: Yes, setting replace=TRUE seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dave2e's comment will fix your issue. Alternatively, you can skip the definition of `pop` and use `rbinom` to generate a sample from the population directly.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:1000){

  sample <- rbinom(n=25, size=1, prob = 0.6)
  df <- rbind(
    df,
    data.frame(mean.prop=mean(sample)))
}

df %>% summarise(se=sd(mean.prop), mean=mean(mean.prop))

          se    mean
1 0.09849019 0.60232
```